# Why is my Eclipse debugging shell's "execute" greyed out?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I wonder if anyone could help me with using Eclipse's debugging shell. I entered a line of code in the debugging shell during a debugging session paused upon a break point, but the execute option is greyed out, as in the following link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkf7w.png

I wonder what are the reasons for this?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the statement first?

Comment: How do I select statement?

Comment: With your mouse or keyboard. I mean literally selecting the text of the statement.

Comment: Where can i select the text of the statement? and what do I do afterwards? Could you provide some instructions, I am not very familiar with eclipse.